# Office.js not loaded for Outlook add-on

Tags: reactjs, office-js, outlook-addin, asp.net-core-3.1

I have worked on Outlook add-in for web, this issue is continuously appearing with all platforms (windows browsers, mac browsers, and outlook desktop) and keep a blank screen on the task pane which prevents the clients from using the add-on.

The issue gone after opening the add-on page from the next attempt.

I am using the CDN version and follow the official doc to add it in header main HTML file:

`<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and the two initialising functions are called as follow:

```
Office.initialize = function (){};

Office.onReady(async function () {....});
```

The exact error appearing in the browser console is:

```
Error: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.
```

My app is SPA React app and hosted on Azure app service.

am I missing any configuration?

Comment: We are unable to reproduce the issue by downloading add-in from app source as well which was mentioned in mail.Can you please share the Incident Id for the bug for further investigation
For this query "Is it safe to move to the second option of using the Office.js library which is to download it using npm and use it in offline mode? " :-If you plan to publish your Office Add-in from AppSource, you must use this CDN reference. Local references are only appropriate for internal, development, and debugging scenarios.

Comment: We are not able to repro this issue using the addin you mentioned from AppSource. Is the issue fixed for you as well?

Comment: No still exists, I worked on a workaround and it is fine.

Comment: I monitor the library using timer and reload the page if failed after 2 seconds...